# Duplicate "graphql" modules cannot be used

Tags: graphql-js

I have found that the [graphql-js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js)  library does not allow dependencies to also use graphql.

You would get the following error

`Duplicate "graphql" modules cannot be used at the same time since different
versions may have different capabilities and behavior. The data from one
version used in the function from another could produce confusing and
spurious results.`

from the following code

```
const express = require('express');
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');
const { GraphQLSchema } = require('graphql'); 
// the module graphql-test-mod-obj-type' has 
// graphql as a depenedency
const myType = require('graphql-test-mod-obj-type');

const app = express();

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({ query: myType })

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  schema,
  graphiql: true
}));

app.listen(4000);
```

I created a small repo and a small public npm package to demonstrate this 
[repo-with-npm-dependency-on-graphql](https://github.com/ghinks/graphql-test-consume-graphql-obj-type.git) .

This can be quite easily worked around by not having the graphql module as a dependency in the module. But surely this is an issue? Or is this a well known thing?

Comment: If NODE_ENV is set to production this check is not carried out. I'm not sure why we have this difference?

Comment: I have tested the production leg, and it will fail silently in this case.  For instance if you call printSchema it will fail to validate the schema.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered this error and resolved it using the following steps:

1. list all available instances of graphql package to check for dependences

   npm ls graphql
2. remove node_modules directory

   rm -rf node_modules
3. delete package-lock.json file
4. add "resolutions" object to package.json

   "resolutions": {
   "graphql": "15.5.0",
   "**/graphql": "15.5.0"
   }
5. Add preinstall script to enforce resolutions options to scripts object in package.json file

   "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
6. install packages again

   npm install

** NOTE***
In my case I also had to change the node version from v18.0 to v17.0 because of some other the apollo/federation package I was using so may be also look at the node dependencies

Comment: This really helped me, but for step 4 with npm I used the "overrides" key in package.json

Answer (score 4):

I had this error in a Strapi project and could solve it with the following commands:

```
yarn cache clean
rm -rf node_modules
```

added in package.json the "resolutions" section. See below:

```
{
  "name": "lighthouse-strapi",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi",
    "generate-api-doc": "node docs/MD_TOC.js README.md README_toc.md"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.5.0",
    "graphql": "^15.6.1",
    "highlight.js": "^10.7.3",
    "knex": "0.21.18",
    "kuzzle-sdk": "^7.7.6",
    "md-to-pdf": "^5.0.0",
    "mysql": "2.18.1",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "pg-connection-string": "^2.5.0",
    "strapi": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-admin": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-connector-bookshelf": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-content-manager": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-email": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-graphql": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-i18n": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-upload": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "3.6.8",
    "strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary": "^3.6.8",
    "strapi-utils": "3.6.8"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "graphql": "^15.6.1",
    "**/graphql": "^15.6.1"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "c192f5ec-e7d1-4747-80d2-24b725ff9b0e"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.16.0 <=14.x.x",
    "npm": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

And finally:

```
yarn install
```

Answer (score 2):

it does appear that this is a longstanding and known issue and is covered [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/491)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Yarn instead of NPM, first thing I would advise trying is switching to NPM since there is apparently a specific issue between the GraphQL package and how Yarn resolves dependencies.

See the Github issues:
- [162](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-yoga/issues/162)
- [1928](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1928#issuecomment-366480975)

Answer (score 0):

Anyone having this issue in Deno with npm specifier imports for `graphql` and `graphql-tools/*`

Just delete `deno.lock` file and rerun, it should work.